# Image manipulation library for mobile application

Tags: c++, image, mobile, bada

I need a C/C++ image manipulation  library for mobile image application, The library should have

Brightness/contrast
Levels
Effects - Grayscale, Sepia and so on

I particularly want to use it on Samsung BADA Platform. I want the the one event hough if it is not optimized for BADA

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/)?